# html content into a page

Tags: php, html

I need to pull the content from the database on the page, but some of this contents have the whole HTML page - with css, head, etc...

What would be the best way prevent having all htlm tags, scripts, css? Would iframe help here?

The most bothering thing is that I'm getting strange characters on the page: �
and as found out it is due to different encoding.

The site has utf-8 encoding and if the content contains different encoding, these signs come out and I cannot replace them. 
The only thing it make them remove was to change my encoding, but this is not the real solution.

If someone could tell me how to remove them, would be really great.

Solution: with your help I checked encoding, but couldn't change it. I set names in mysql_query to UTF-8, and stripped unusefull tags. Now it seems ok.
Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Why html content on the database has full tags and custom css? What do you expect to happen and how you're going to display html in your pages?

Comment: Also, the second question you have depends on the solution chosen for the first question. So I'd suggest removing the second question, deciding on what to do for the first one, then, if the second question is still valid, post it as a separate question.

Comment: @Ghigo: I think he might be storing html and css in database like CKEDITOR does.

Comment: try preg_replace, but still wrong logic for filling HTML and so in your DB

Comment: @Ghigo unfortunately - there is nothing I can do here - I mean - I've got the table with all these data and was surprised as well ...only when this characters appeared - I found out what data I'm dealing with.

Comment: @AngelM., what exactly does the HTML contain? Does it have `<head>` tags or `<html>` tags? Or just contents that would go inside `<body>`?

Comment: @rid it contains everything: html, head, css, and then body with the content. of course - i need only body - I tried to strip tags - which worked, but those characters remained there - and I couldn't find a way to remove them

Comment: @rid yes, few records that I checked use iso-8859-1, I thought - and also tested - I changed encoding to our site to be the same, and this worked. I'd like to keep utf-8 and also - I don't think is ok displaying the whole html content

Comment: @AngelM., then I think you should go the `iconv()` way, as detailed by an answer (replacing ISO-8859-15 with your original encoding), but instead of doing this live, maybe it would be a better idea to save the results, with all the tags you don't care about stripped, directly in the database, then go to the source of the problem, see who's generating these and tell them to do it the right way...

Comment: @rid thanks, I haven't thinking of iconv() and I told the developer who generated this - not sure if something will be changed

Comment: @AngelM., if it's not sure that they'll change anything, then live is probably the best option (keeping in mind the error-prone-ness and performance hit), right after talking to the manager about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  � tags in fact might not be due to encoding, the problem might be the content that is stored in the database. 
Check for double quotes like **“** which are supposed to be **"**, more so if the data in the table was copy pasted.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have no chance apart an ugly iframe. About encoding, you should check db encoding, connection encoding and convert as needed. Use `iconv` for full control over conversion, for example:

```
$html=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15"."//TRANSLIT//IGNORE",$html]);
```

In this case, you're going to lose some characters not mapped in ISO-8859-15. Consider moving your whole site to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks ... yes, I don't like iframes .. I'll let you know if will help